# Why does my function not run?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a slogan game where the user inputs the company's name that uses the slogan. The games in early development and if missing a but my current code does not work.

```html
<html land="en">
<head>
  <title>Whats that ???</title>
  <script>
    function checkAnswer()
    {
      var answer = document.getElementById("answerInput");
        var theAnswer = answer.value;
        document.getElementById("correct/incorrent").innerHTML += theanswer;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="game-container">
    <div id="slogan">
      <p>Das Auto</p>
    </div>
    <div id="answer">
      <p>Answer<p>
      <input id="answerInput" type="text">
      <input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkAnswer">
    </div>
    <div id="correct/incorrent">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
```

Tnx Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed syntax errors:

1. `theanswer != theAnswer`, missing camel case letter "A"
2. need to invoke function by `()` rather than just stating its reference `checkAnswer`

```html
<html land="en">
<head>
    <title>Whats that ???</title>
    <script>
        function checkAnswer() {
            var answer = document.getElementById("answerInput");
            var theAnswer = answer.value;
            document.getElementById("correct/incorrent").innerHTML += theAnswer;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game-container">
        <div id="slogan">
            <p>Das Auto</p>
        </div>
        <div id="answer">
            <p>Answer<p>
            <input id="answerInput" type="text">
            <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="checkAnswer()">
        </div>
        <div id="correct/incorrent">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event executes any javascript between the quotes. You were just referencing a function, not calling it.

```
onclick="checkAnswer()"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html land="en">
<head>
<title>Whats that ???</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="game-container">
    <div id="slogan">
        <p>Das Auto</p>
    </div>
    <div id="answer">
        <p>Answer<p>
        <input id="answerInput" type="text">
        <input type="button" value="Check">
    </div>
    <div id="correct/incorrent">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
<script>
   var btn = document.getElementById("answerInput");
   var ans = document.getElementById("correct/incorrent"); 

   btn.onClick = function (){
    var answer = document.getElementById("answerInput");
    var theAnswer = answer.value;
    ans.innerHTML += theAnswer;    
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```